# How to have find only search for files in changed directories?

Tags: command-line, shell-script, find, performance

Currently I'm repeatedly doing a 'find' that's too slow. I'm searching for non-hidden executable files within "$root", excluding "$root/bin":

```
find "$root" -type f -perm -o+x -not -path "$root/bin/*" \( ! -regex '.*/\..*' \)
```

I'd like to restrict find to only look in directories with mtimes older than a certain time. I still want it to recurse into old directories' subdirectories, but I don't want it to check the regular files inside unless the directory passes my mtime check. Is it possible to do this with GNU find or do I need two invocations, one to find the directories and another to check the files inside?

Comment: I don't think that will make things faster.  It's the `stat` that makes things slow.  And to recurse into subdirectories, it'll have to `stat` each file to see whether it's a directory or not.  Or is it OK to prune the whole directory tree if one of its ancestors is too new?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
find "$root" -type d -mtime -1 ! -path "$root/bin*" -exec find "{}" -maxdepth 1 -type f -executable  \;
```

It's not just one `find` run, however maxdepth should accelerate the result.

Comment: For clarity I ended up doing two finds with a loop, but I used the maxdepth trick on the inner find so they're functionally the same. Thanks :)